# Using class (.cs) files in simple web site.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, app-code

Alright I am a bit of a newb when it comes to ASP.net. I am used to PHP.

Anyway, I am working on a website that is connected to my server via ftp. Everything is working fine, except I just added some classes in the App_Code folder. I cannot access those classes when I go to the page on the web.

I was researching a bit and everyone said I needed to publish the website. Well I did that, and it completely broke. I had to restore from a backup and lost a lot. My own fault though.

The classes work if I am using them on a local web site, but not on the web. Any guidance here? I've tried moving the App_Code folder around with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the web server doesnt directly execute a .cs file like a .php file. a web server has registered handlers associated with a file extension. when a request arrives, the extension of the file is used to find a dll to process the request. the asp.net web pages model is an easy onramp for people coming from php. http://www.asp.net/web-pages